# Dialog flow Agent Query with input String in Japanese / Arabic

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using dialog flow V1 Apis to query the agent. There is a scenario where the input query string is not english. The language I want to send in is a Japanese / Arabic string

**Sample Request**

endpoint = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910";

JSON Data

```
{
    "originalRequest": {
        "data": {
            "incomingMessage": "朝食時間は何ですか？"
        }
    },
    "lang": "ja",
    "query": "朝食時間は何ですか？",
    "sessionId": "###########"
}
```

In dialog flow agent, it is received as

```
æé£æéã¯ä½ã§ããï¼
```

How do i pass it to the query endpoint so that the dialog flow agent can read the input query in the language i send.

I am also aware that Dialog flow will not Arabic. I tried with a Japanese string as well and ended up with same kind of results. I tried changing the "lang" property to "ja", still it didn't work. Should I encode the "query" property in a certain format?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Dialogflow does not currently support Arabic. In terms of working with Japanese if you're only interested in having it all in that language then you'll need to set the agent's language root language to Japanese:

Go to your agent's **Settings** ⚙ > **Languages** tab > Choose the language > **Save**

And if you'll need multi-language agent then here's the [reference docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/multi-language)